# Merge pandas dataframes and create derived column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

Given 2 pandas dataframes

**Med_DF**

```
Key Med
 1  A
 1  B
 1  C
 2  A
 2  F
 3  A
 3  C
 3  E
 4  A
 4  B
 4  C
 4  D
```

**Key_DF**

```
Key ID
1   A1
2   A2
3   A3
4   A4
5   A5
```

How can I merge the two without duplicate `Keys`, match the `ID` with each `Key` and create a derived variable in a new column? The derived variable will return the number of meds per `ID` or blank/`Nan` if 0, as shown in the Result_DF below

**Result_DF**

```
Key ID  Med
1   A1  3
2   A2  2
3   A3  3
4   A4  4
5   A5
```

**What I've tried**

I'm sure my solution is archaic and inefficient, which is why I am asking for a cleaner, potentially faster solution. Nonetheless, I create Excel formulas via loops to populate the derived column and to lookup the `ID` matching the `Key`.

```
# read in Med and Key files into dataframes
Med_DF = pd.read_csv(med_file, usecols = ['Key', 'Med'], encoding = 'utf-8', keep_default_na=False, na_values=[''])

Key_DF = pd.read_csv(key_file, usecols = ['Key', 'ID'], encoding = 'utf-8', keep_default_na=False, na_values=[''])

# add empty ID column to Med_DF
Med_DF.insert(0, "ID", "")

# assign length of dataframes
length_of_med = len(Med_DF)
length_of_key = len(Key_DF)

# create empty lists for formulas
med_countif = []
med_vlookup = []

# med VLOOKUP formulas 
for i in range(2,length_of_med+2):
    formula = '=VLOOKUP($B{0},Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)'.format(i)
    med_vlookup.append(formula)

# med COUNTIF formulas 
for i in range(2,length_of_key+2):
    formula = 
   '=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,$B{0})=0,"",COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,$B{0}))'.format(i)
    med_countif.append(formula)

# write formulas to columns
Key_DF.loc[:, "Meds"] = meds_formulas
Med_DF.loc[:, "Key"] = meds_vlookup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) or [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for counting values, values are converted to `float`s, because at least one `NaN` - not matched value:

```
df = Key_DF.join(Med_DF['Key'].value_counts().rename('Med'), on='Key')
```

Alternative:

```
df = Key_DF.join(Med_DF.groupby('Key').size().rename('Med'), on='Key')
```

---

```
print (df)
   Key  ID  Med
0    1  A1  3.0
1    2  A2  2.0
2    3  A3  3.0
3    4  A4  4.0
4    5  A5  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use pandas merge with `Key_DF` and `Med_DF` on the Key with left outer join.
2. With the result `groupby` the `Key, ID` with `Med` count function

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.merge(Key_DF,Med_DF[['Med','Key']],on='Key',how='left').groupby(["Key","ID"]).Med.agg({"Med":"count"})
```

```
df

Key ID  Med
1   A1  3
2   A2  2
3   A3  3
4   A4  4
5   A5  0
```

Here I am getting 5th row as 0 as I am using count. So, if the requirement is to get Nan we can add one more step to replace 0 with Nan

```
import numpy as np
df.Med.replace({0:np.nan})
```